RHEL 9 nmcli how to change permanently ethtool settings?
[root@101 system-connections]# nmcli c modify enp2s0f0 ethtool.tx-checksumming off
Error: invalid property 'tx-checksumming': 'tx-checksumming' not among [feature-esp-hw-offload, feature-esp-tx-csum-hw-offload, feature-fcoe-mtu, feature-gro, feature-gso, feature-highdma, feature-hw-tc-offload, feature-l2-fwd-offload, feature-loopback, feature-lro, feature-macsec-hw-offload, feature-ntuple, feature-rx, feature-rxhash, feature-rxvlan, feature-rx-all, feature-rx-fcs, feature-rx-gro-hw, feature-rx-gro-list, feature-rx-udp-gro-forwarding, feature-rx-udp_tunnel-port-offload, feature-rx-vlan-filter, feature-rx-vlan-stag-filter, feature-rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse, feature-sg, feature-tls-hw-record, feature-tls-hw-rx-offload, feature-tls-hw-tx-offload, feature-tso, feature-tx, feature-txvlan, feature-tx-checksum-fcoe-crc, feature-tx-checksum-ipv4, feature-tx-checksum-ipv6, feature-tx-checksum-ip-generic, feature-tx-checksum-sctp, feature-tx-esp-segmentation, feature-tx-fcoe-segmentation, feature-tx-gre-csum-segmentation, feature-tx-gre-segmentation, feature-tx-gso-list, feature-tx-gso-partial, feature-tx-gso-robust, feature-tx-ipxip4-segmentation, feature-tx-ipxip6-segmentation, feature-tx-nocache-copy, feature-tx-scatter-gather, feature-tx-scatter-gather-fraglist, feature-tx-sctp-segmentation, feature-tx-tcp6-segmentation, feature-tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation, feature-tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation, feature-tx-tcp-segmentation, feature-tx-tunnel-remcsum-segmentation, feature-tx-udp-segmentation, feature-tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation, feature-tx-udp_tnl-segmentation, feature-tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert, coalesce-adaptive-rx, coalesce-adaptive-tx, coalesce-pkt-rate-high, coalesce-pkt-rate-low, coalesce-rx-frames, coalesce-rx-frames-irq, coalesce-rx-frames-high, coalesce-rx-frames-low, coalesce-rx-usecs, coalesce-rx-usecs-irq, coalesce-rx-usecs-high, coalesce-rx-usecs-low, coalesce-sample-interval, coalesce-stats-block-usecs, coalesce-tx-frames, coalesce-tx-frames-irq, coalesce-tx-frames-high, coalesce-tx-frames-low, coalesce-tx-usecs, coalesce-tx-usecs-irq, coalesce-tx-usecs-high, coalesce-tx-usecs-low, pause-autoneg, pause-rx, pause-tx, ring-rx, ring-rx-jumbo, ring-rx-mini, ring-tx].

but tx-checksumming is clearly in ethtool:
$ sudo ethtool -k enp2s0f0                     
Features for enp2s0f0:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: off
    tx-checksum-ipv4: off
    tx-checksum-ip-generic: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-ipv6: off
    tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-sctp: off
scatter-gather: off
    tx-scatter-gather: off
    tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: off
    tx-tcp-segmentation: off
    tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off
    tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation: off
    tx-tcp6-segmentation: off

Why doesn't nmcli find the ethtool settings?
Just migrated and I already have issues with these new keyfiles.
RHEL 9's documentation clearly specifies nmcli is the way to go to permanently set ethtool parameters.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/configuring-ethtool-settings-in-networkmanager-connection-profiles_configuring-and-managing-networking

All the solutions I found specify it should be done using /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ but RHEL 9 deprecated them for their keyfiles.

nmcli has its own tools and that are independent of those for ethtool.
If you just want tx-checksumming to be off, that has already been done according to the output.
The only ethtool properties that are available for nmcli those that are listed in the error message that you received.

Thanks, how can I set permanently ethtool settings in RHEL 9 then?


[root@101 system-connections]# nmcli c modify enp2s0f0 ethtool.tx-checksumming off
Error: invalid property 'tx-checksumming': 'tx-checksumming' not among [feature-esp-hw-offload, ..., ring-tx].

This error message seems pretty clear. The property ethtool.tx-checksumming does not exist, nmcli tells you which properties exist instead. They are also listed in man nm-settings.
"tx-checksumming" is also not an option known to kernel. This is only known to the ethtool utility, which uses that as an alias for a set of tx-checksum-* offload features. This alias is not supported by NetworkManager, instead set the individual ones.
The related options are called:
$ man nm-settings |grep feature-tx-checksum
       ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-fcoe-crc
       ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-ip-generic
       ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-ipv4
       ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-ipv6
       ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-sctp

which makes it
nmcli c modify enp2s0f0 \
       ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-fcoe-crc off \
       ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-ip-generic off \
       ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-ipv4 off \
       ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-ipv6 off \
       ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-sctp off

